# NodeJS - Serve file with throttled speed

Tags: node.js, pipe

I'm quite new to NodeJS and trying different stuff.

What I was able to do is to download a file going using the following code:

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res){


  var file = 'public/songs/myfile.mp3';

  var filename = path.basename(file);
  var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);

  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);
  res.setHeader('Content-Length', file.length);

  var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);

  filestream.pipe(res);
});
```

This works well, now what I'm trying to achive is see if it's possible to throttle the download speed. Like if someone tries to download the file it will download at max 1 Mbps (for example).

I've tried to use this code: https://gist.github.com/4poc/1454516

When I load the page it seems to load indefinetly, but I think that the problem is

```
filestream.pipe(limitStream);
```

Since that no response is given.

**How can I implement what I would like to do? Or how I can fix the code I tried to use?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `req` and `res` objects are streams, so you can pipe on the response:

```
var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);

filestream.pipe(limitStream).pipe(res);
```

fwiw: every time you call `pipe()` you get back a new stream. The above is the same as this:

```
var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);

var throttleStream = filestream.pipe(limitStream);

throttleStream.pipe(res);
```

This is important to understand because it's tempting to do this, but it won't do what you expect:

```
var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);

filestream.pipe(limitStream);

filestream.pipe(res);
```

Comment: I've tried "filestream.pipe(limitStream).pipe(res);" which made sense to me. But unfortunately what I get is an empty file immediately when I load the page. 
In the meanwhile I see the NodeJs log printing informations like:


"emit pause, will resume in: 8.13333333333344ms
emit resume
emit data
emit pause, will resume in: 1.3333333333332575ms
emit end
emit resume" 

which is the script working

Comment: hmm, something doesn't seem right then. If you simply do `filestream.pipe(res);` - do you get the file response as you expect (not throttled)?

Comment: Edit: no you are right, I must have messed up something... Will answer later :)

Comment: Ok it's working,I started again and the problem was solved.. I don't know where I messed up..

There is still a smaller issue that maybe you can help resolve. I had to remove the header Content-lenght because I don't know how to read the size of the file with "createReadStream". How I could read the file size so I can set the header? :)

Cheers

Comment: You use [fs.stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) to get that type of information. Run the stat first and then create the read stream, set the response headers, and pipe on the throttle and response.